# How to let QTableView automatically update content even when it is not focused?

Tags: c++, qt, crash

I use a `QTimer` object to scan computer memory to detect any data changed, and finally showing these data in GUI with `QTableView`.
But problem is when the program window is not focused, no changes are detected. As soon as the window is focused again, data changes in Gui in no time.

My question is how to let the tableview update content automatically?

To follow MVC style, I decided to use `QTableView` instead of `QTableWidget`. Indeed, it is convenient to update data as I only need to deal with a "model" but not `QTableView` after binding the model with it.

`QTableView` object is in Gui thread (view level), and `QStandardItemModel` is used in another thread (control level). For this issue, after googling, I tried :

```
QModelIndex t1 = index(i, 3); 
QModelIndex t2 = index(i, 5);
emit dataChanged(t1, t2);
```

when doing `dataChanged`. It is not working and when I found no problem on the model side, then I also tried:

```
connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [&]() {
        ui.searchTableV->viewport()->update();
        });
    timer.start();
```

at the very beginning of GUI class construction. Sometimes it is working, but usually it raised "Access Violation".

Personally, I never expect there would be an issue like this, as everything was working fine with `QTableWidget` before. It seems that I need to do something with subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` to make the `QTableView` more robust after I found [this on QT forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/17193/solved-custom-delegate-to-repaint-if-data-changes-in-model). But I don't want to do so, I think there should be a simpler way.

Also, I wonder if this issue is a bug or it is just designed to behave like this.

Comment: _QStandardItemModel is used in another thread_ This might be the problem. GUI classes are usually not thread safe. I assume that's also true for `QStandardItemModel`. I did [google "QStandardItemModel thread safe"](https://www.google.com/search?q=qstandarditemmodel+thread+safe) which convinced me about this.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to reproduce your described behavior, but I was not able to do so. My app works as desired and it really does not matter if it will lose focus. There are also no crashes. Maybe you are doing something different.

**Worker.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker();
    void setModel(QStandardItemModel* model);

public slots:
    void addItems();

private:
    QStandardItemModel* mModel{ nullptr };
};
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
#include "Worker.h"

Worker::Worker()
{

}

void Worker::setModel(QStandardItemModel* model)
{
    mModel = model;
}

void Worker::addItems()
{
    for (;;) {
        mModel->appendRow(new QStandardItem("Item"));
        QThread::currentThread()->msleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include "Worker.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto frame = new QFrame;
    frame->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
    auto view = new QTreeView;
    auto model = new QStandardItemModel;
    view->setModel(model);
    auto worker = new Worker;
    worker->setModel(model);
    auto thread = new QThread;
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
    frame->layout()->addWidget(view);
    auto btnStart = new QPushButton("Start add items");
    QObject::connect(btnStart, &QPushButton::clicked, worker, &Worker::addItems);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(btnStart);
    frame->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```